# System.CalloutException: IO Exception: External server did not return any content

Tags: integration, .net

I am trying to make a webservice callout. I am getting the below error.
System.CalloutException: IO Exception: External server did not return any content.

The webservice is publicy accessible and it is working fine in the SOAP UI Tool.

What else should I be doing to access the webservice ?

Thanks in Advance,
Sri.

Comment: Can you put your code? Did service log that SF send something to it? Is SF authorised as well?

Comment: did you add your remote site url to the remote site white list settings in salesforce?

Comment: Yes, I have added the site url in remote site settings.

Comment: Have you set the authentication header? 
See HTTP Header Support
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts

Comment: tempuriOrg.BasicHttpBinding_IDepots stub = new tempuriOrg.BasicHttpBinding_IDepots();
stub.clientCertName_x = 'XXXXX';
stub.clientCert_x = 'YYYYY';
stub.clientCertPasswd_x = '**********';
stub.timeout_x = 60000;

System.debug(stub.GetStandardPriceList());

Comment: Check the Debug log for the CALLOUT_REQUEST entry. It will include the SOAP envelope in a developer edition org. You can then compare this with the working call from SOAP UI.

Comment: I have tried removing the authentication on the webservice and it is returning the data now. May be the problem was related to Salesforce not supporting the HTTP authentication header. How to resolve this issue with authentication ?

Answer (score 1):

Authentication information can be passed through HTTP headers or SOAP headers, that might not be the issue.

Please make sure that the SOAP message built in the callout conforms to the sample SOAP message given by your service provider. If sample is not available from the service provider compare it with the working SoapUI request message.

Apex callout by default inserts empty SOAP header "env:Header/>", the issue can be as simple as the callout SOAP message containing this empty header which the server does not expect.